# How to get value from XML string with Node.js

Tags: xml, node.js

Let's say you have this xml:

```
<yyy:response xmlns:xxx='http://domain.com'> 
    <yyy:success> 
        <yyy:data>some-value</yyy:data> 
    </yyy:success> 
</yyy:response>
```

How would I retrieve the value in between `<yyy:data>` using Node.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[node-xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) library will help you.

```js
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
var xml = '\
<yyy:response xmlns:xxx="http://domain.com">\
    <yyy:success>\
        <yyy:data>some-value</yyy:data>\
    </yyy:success>\
</yyy:response>';
parser.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result['yyy:success']['yyy:data']);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it easier with [camaro](https://github.com/tuananh/camaro)

```
const camaro = require('camaro')

const xml = `<yyy:response xmlns:xxx='http://example.com'> <yyy:success><yyy:data>some-value</yyy:data> </yyy:success></yyy:response>`

const template = {
    data: '//yyy:data'
}

console.log(camaro(xml, template))
```

Output:

```
{ data: 'some-value' }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to parse it for data extraction, simply use regexp :

```
  str = "<yyy:response xmlns:xxx='http://example.com'> <yyy:success><yyy:data>some-value</yyy:data> </yyy:success></yyy:response>";
  var re = new RegExp("<yyy:data>(.*?)</yyy:data?>", "gmi");

  while(res = re.exec(str)){ console.log(res[1])}

 // some-value
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need a library to parse the XML. Core Node does not provide XML parsing.

You'll find a list of them here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-xml

I would recommend using libxmljs

Answer (score 0):

Use [XMLDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom) library A JavaScript implementation of W3C DOM for Node.js, Rhino and the browser. Fully compatible with W3C DOM level2; and some compatible with level3. Supports DOMParser and XMLSerializer interface such as in browser.

Answer (score -4):

There are plenty of methods available to extract information from xml file,
I have used xpath select method to fetch the tag values.
https://cloudtechnzly.blogspot.in/2017/07/how-to-extract-information-from-xml.html

Comment: Linking a solution is not a good answer. Please summarise the essence of the solution here or give a code sample.

Comment: checkout this link ,then u may get some ideas   https://cloudtechnzly.blogspot.in/2017/08/xml-to-json-conversion.html