# Extract the JSON file using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following valid JSON in the following way,

```
{
  "cancelled": false,
  "text": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<PrintLetterBarcodeData uid=\"345135084445\" name=\"Venkatasiva M\" gender=\"M\" yob=\"1985\" co=\"S/O Narayana\" vtc=\"Pamidi vari palem\" dist=\"Guntur\" state=\"Andhra Pradesh\" pc=\"522112\"/>",
  "format": "QR_CODE"
}
```

How do i extract the uid and personal details(name, gender and yob) from the JSON file.

Comment: This answer I believe will solve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611450/how-to-get-value-from-xml-string-with-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to convert your *JSON* file text and that is possible by below sort way:

```
//Your JSON file data...
var returnJSONFile = {
  "cancelled": false,
  "text": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<PrintLetterBarcodeData uid=\"345135084445\" name=\"Venkatasiva M\" gender=\"M\" yob=\"1985\" co=\"S/O Narayana\" vtc=\"Pamidi vari palem\" dist=\"Guntur\" state=\"Andhra Pradesh\" pc=\"522112\"/>",
  "format": "QR_CODE"
};

//Object Initialization...
var x2js = new X2JS();

//Convert XML to JSON...
var xml2Json = JSON.stringify(x2js.xml_str2json(returnJSONFile.text));
alert(xml2Json);
```

Please check my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Narendrad/6abvuv94/1/) for more understanding.

I accomplish this by using [x2js library](http://code.google.com/p/x2js/).

This library provides *XML to JSON* (JavaScript Objects) and vice versa javascript conversion functions. The library is very small and doesn't require any other additional libraries.

> API functions
>
> 1. new X2JS() - to create your instance to access all library 
>      functionality. Also you could specify optional configuration options here
> 2. X2JS.xml2json - Convert XML specified as DOM Object to JSON
> 3. X2JS.json2xml - Convert JSON to XML DOM Object
> 4. X2JS.xml_str2json - Convert XML specified as string to JSON
> 5. X2JS.json2xml_str - Convert JSON to XML string

Hope this help you well!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but in a simple way you can get text (yours xml) from json. Then you pass this to the following function which will return you json of input XML.

```
// Changes XML to JSON
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

The function will return you json so you can easily extract desired node.