# Error: Non-whitespace before first tag. in node.js body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
require('body-parser-xml')(bodyParser);

function test(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body);
 res.sendStatus(200);
}


module.exports = {
    middleware: [
        bodyParser.json(),
        bodyParser.text(),
        bodyParser.xml({
            xmlParseOptions: {
                normalize: true,
                normalizeTags: true, 
                explicitArray: true
            }
        })
    ],
'/test': [{
        get: test
    }],
}
```

In above code, I'm trying to extract `application/xml, text/xml, application/json, text, text.plain, application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

But I'm getting the error `Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.` when I pass raw body content with `text/plain` header.

How can I use body-parser middleware to extract all of the above request body content?

Comment: `app.use(require('bodyparser').json());` ==> get data from req.body

Comment: @muthukumar Can I extract xml data using this method?

Comment: Not sure @santhosh  please follow the Blow Link This might Help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611450/how-to-get-value-from-xml-string-with-node-js]

Comment: @muthukumar My problem is I'm not able to get raw body when I specify `bodyParser.xml()`. But when I remove this from middleware, I'm getting raw body content. How can I get xml content now if I remove `bodyParser.xml()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong, it looks like a bug to me. The code for `body-parser-xml` is quite short so it isn't difficult to find the problem.

It creates an internal instance of `bodyParser.text` with the `type` set to `['*/xml', '+xml']`. So far so good. It then runs the request through the 'text' parser to read in the XML as a string. If the `content-type` of the request is `text/plain` (or any other non-XML type) it will be ignored. That's also fine. The problem is the next step:

https://github.com/fiznool/body-parser-xml/blob/3cf7784d6fae61d1d877da54ca56f31b2642975c/index.js#L27

```
if(typeof req.body !== 'string') { return next(); }
```

It assumes that if `req.body` is a string then it must have come from its internal text parser. But that is an incorrect assumption as `req.body` could already be a string from the earlier middleware.

I suggest you file a bug against `body-parser-xml`.

The easiest way to avoid this problem is to switch the order of `bodyParser.text` and `bodyParser.xml`.

Comment: Swapping the order helped.